# Related questions when asking

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, related-questions

Is it possible to add a "related question" pull-down menu to the mobile apps (I use iOS) so to avoid duplicate questions? It is a bit inconvenient to search your question before asking one. Also, the search engine for duplicates are way much better than the normal search engine.

Comment: It doesn't exist today but it's a good idea.  I don't think the API has an endpoint for it yet.

Comment: ...API? I'm sorry, I don't understand...? :P

Comment: "API" is a technical term - it's how the app interacts with the site. @Brian is stating that the API doesn't currently have the required information to include "related questions" in the app - so it would be a bigger job to add this feature in.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining. So it won't be added in in the near future?

Comment: @Brian three months later, any advance in the API side that might bring us any hope? :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I finally got a local instance of search working and it looks like /similar was just missing a couple fixes from the web.  I'm going to start designing the UI.

Comment: Awesome @Brian, thanks! :)

Comment: Done!  In the beta channel now.